# How to flush with Flux (Reactor)?

Tags: java, spring, express, compression, flux

I want to subscribe to a server-sent event (see example below)

Between the client-browser and the java server is another application which uses the compress nodejs middleware.

This middleware causes a ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING when I try to reach this server-sent event via a browser.

In order to get this up an running I should do a .flush() which is described here in more detail (for a nodejs application): https://github.com/expressjs/compression/blob/master/README.md#server-sent-events

My code currently looks like this:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/fluxTest", produces = MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM_VALUE)
public Flux<String> getFluxStream(HttpServletRequest request) {
    String[] randomNames = { "Steve", "Dirk", "Jens", "Rene"};

    return Flux.interval(Duration.ofSeconds(1))
               .map(sequence -> "{\"name\": \"" + randomNames[new Random().nextInt(randomNames.length)] + "\"}");
}
```

How can I trigger a .flush() in java like described in the nodejs compression documentation?

Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

If you add a header("Cache-Control", "no-transform") to the response, the body will not be transformed by the compress library. I know that this not the fix to this 
issue, but nevertheless a temporary workaround.